# Ошибка при установке Bower

Tags: node.js, linux

Установил NodeJS, nmp установился автоматом, пробую через npm поставить bower:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Выдает:

```
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/user/tmp/npm-27904-09gBEpPM'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/user/tmp/npm-27904-09gBEpPM']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/user/tmp/npm-27904-09gBEpPM' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-44-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.26
npm ERR! path /home/user/tmp/npm-27904-09gBEpPM
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/user/tmp/npm-27904-09gBEpPM'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Потому что -g (надо запускать sudo npm install -g bower)

Ещё: /home/user/tmp/ не принадлежит user почему-то, сделайте

```
sudo chown -R user:user /home/user/tmp
```

Comment: Спасибо, пробовал с sudo, но не получалось, потом переставил node js, но с sudo уже не пробовал.